# How to test component which uses redux toolkit?

Tags: react-native

How to test a component that uses Redux Toolkit?

I've tried the following, and I couldn't find any guides on how to do it properly.

here is the component -

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {
  incrementAction,
  decrementAction,
  incrementAsync,
} from '../reducers/CounterSlice';
import AppButton from '../../../../components/AppButton';
import Snackbar from 'react-native-snackbar';

const CounterMainScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hi</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CounterMainScreen;
```

here is slice -

```
import {
  createSlice,
  createAsyncThunk,
  ThunkDispatch,
  AnyAction,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {increment} from '../service/CounterService';

const CounterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
    status: '',
    error: '',
  },
  reducers: {
    incrementAction: state => {
      state.count += 1;
    },
    decrementAction: state => {
      state.count -= 1;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, state => {
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.error = '';
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.error = '';
        let count = action.payload;
        state.count += count;
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.error.message!;
      });
  },
});

export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk<number, void, any>(
  'counter/incrementAsync',
  async () => {
    let counterModel = await increment();
    return counterModel;
  },
);

export const {incrementAction, decrementAction} = CounterSlice.actions;
export default CounterSlice.reducer;
```

store -

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import CounterSlice from "../features/counter/reducers/CounterSlice";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: CounterSlice,
    
  },
  middleware:[thunk],
});

export default store;
```

test file -

```
import React from 'react';
import store from '../../../src/store/store';
import {
  render,
  screen,
  fireEvent,
  waitFor,
} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import {useDispatch, useSelector, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import CounterMainScreen from '../../../src/features/counter/screen/CounterMainScreen';

describe('CounterMainScreen', () => {
  it('renders the "Hi" text', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CounterMainScreen />
      </Provider>,
    );

    // Use getByText to find the "Hi" text element
    const hiText = getByText('Hi');

    // Assert that the "Hi" text element is present in the rendered component
    expect(hiText).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I'm getting an error saying, 'Unable to find an element with text: Hi,' when I try running the test case without a provider in test file the test passes, but it doesn't work when I wrap the component in a provider in the test file could be issue related to provider or redux config in test file.